# Analyze fsk signal using fft in android

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, fft

I am recording a fsk signal with sample rate of 8000, it contains two frequencies, 800Hz for '1' and 400Hz for '0', the encoded message is the char '8' (00111000) eahc bit is represented using 16384 samples. I used the following code to capture the audio bytes, the only difference is that I am writing them to a ByteArrayOutputStream. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432398/audio-recorder-in-android-process-the-audio-bytes

After I finish the recording, I send to my FFT function chunks of 16384 samples every time to analyze the frequency which was played. For some reason, sometimes it works(I manage to extract the correct bits), and sometimes it doesn't 0.0, in one of my debugs I saw that the first frequency it analyzes is 1190Hz approximately when it should capure 400Hz approximately, another wierd thing happens is the sixth bit keeps giving me 800hz when it should be 400 Hz. I checked the FFT result vector (magnitude) and saw that the 400Hz frequency is also present and its magnitude is higher than the one for 800Hz so I assumed this is the bit '0'.
What am I doing wrong?

Code for audio process to extract the bits:

```
private void ExtractDataBits() 
{
    byte[] byteArrayData = ByteArrayAudioData.toByteArray();
    sExtractedBits="";
    double binSize =((double)sampleRate/numberOfFFTPoints);//fftpoints= 16384
    int HighFreqPos =(int) (freqOfHighTone/binSize);
    int LowFreqPos =(int) (freqOfLowTone/binSize);

    double[] daOriginalSine = convertBytes2SineWave(byteArrayData);
    double[] smallArray;
    int NumOfRuns = daOriginalSine.length/numberOfFFTPoints;
    int startIndex = 0;

    while(NumOfRuns > 0)
    {
        smallArray = new double[numberOfFFTPoints];
        System.arraycopy(daOriginalSine, startIndex, smallArray, 0, numberOfFFTPoints);
        double[] fftRes = calculateFFT(smallArray);
        if(mPeakPos == HighFreqPos)
            sExtractedBits += "1";
        else if(mPeakPos ==LowFreqPos)
            sExtractedBits += "0";
        else
        {
            if(fftRes[HighFreqPos] > fftRes[HighFreqPos])
                sExtractedBits+="1";
            else
                sExtractedBits+="0";
        }
        startIndex = startIndex + numberOfFFTPoints;
        NumOfRuns--;
    }
}
```

the calculateFFt method:

```
public double[] calculateFFT(double[] signalChunk)
{           
    double mMaxFFTSample;
    double temp;
    Complex[] y;
    Complex[] complexSignal = new Complex[numberOfFFTPoints];
    double[] absSignal = new double[numberOfFFTPoints/2];

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFFTPoints; i++)
    {
        temp = signalChunk[i];
        complexSignal[i] = new Complex(temp,0.0);
    }

    y = FFT.fft(complexSignal);

    mMaxFFTSample = 0.0;
    mPeakPos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < (numberOfFFTPoints/2); i++)
    {
         absSignal[i] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y[i].re(), 2) + Math.pow(y[i].im(), 2));
         if(absSignal[i] > mMaxFFTSample)
         {
             mMaxFFTSample = absSignal[i];
             mPeakPos = i;
         } 
    }
     return absSignal;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned previously, using an FFT-based approach for this is like trying to use a sledgehammer to crack a walnut - you'll just end up with a big mess. Keep going, and when you're ready to re-evaluate then take a look at more appropriate methods.

Comment: What do you expect the line `if(fftRes[HighFreqPos] > fftRes[HighFreqPos])` to do? Did you mean `if(fftRes[HighFreqPos] > fftRes[LowFreqPos])`? Mind you, in that case you are probably better off with `if(mPeakPos > (HighFreqPos+LowFreqPos)/2)`, but as Paul mentioned there are other better options.

Comment: You're not windowing your signal, your fft may be overlapping parts of adjacent bits, one target is a harmonic of the other so harmonic distortion could cause false results (especially without a good window), you're using a 16k sample FFT to distinguish between two signals that both fit in only 20 samples. Look into the Goertzel algortihm instead, and if you can tweak the frequencies so one isn't an integer multiple of the other.

Comment: @SleuthEye thank you I didn't see this one. why should I use the second condition?

Comment: @Katie thank you for your explanation, I changed the frequencies to 934Hz and 510Hz and I still get a frequency with a magnitude higher than those two, is it still considered  harmonic distortion?

Comment: The second condition (`if(mPeakPos > (HighFreqPos+LowFreqPos)/2`) comes from selecting the closest frequency in the set of expected values. It helps by ignoring small frequency jitters in the original signal and by associating strong-signal-plus-noise with the most likely nearby strong-signal. Also it looks like you may need some filtering to get rid of spikes outside the expected ranges (by e.g. limiting the peak search to a subset of the bins, something which is implicitly done if you choose the Goertzel algorithm).

Comment: @SleuthEye I see, I did this condition because I want to analyze the first bit which is '0', it gives me some other frequency so I check which magnitude is higher, but when I try to analyze the frequency associated with the bit '1' it manages to give me the correct frequency, what is the reason reson I see other frequency associated with '0'?

Comment: Does your input signal include noise? What does your signal look like in an spectrogram (tools such as Matlab or audacity might help)? If you are starting off with clean tones (no noise, and no wrap-around type distortions), and the decoder is perfectly synchronized with the signal (which could be the case in your controlled test environment), your decoder could work (despite it failing when you start looking at real-life noisy signals).

Comment: @SleuthEye I read some stuff, I think my problem is with overtones, the frequency which kept showing up for 510 was 1530, so I used the following article to do the HPS method - http://cnx.org/contents/8b900091-908f-42ad-b93d-806415434b46@2/Pitch_Detection_Algorithms It seems to work well, now I get the frequency I needed (510Hz), so my question now is how can I handle the problem with overlapping bits? Edit:  I found some pseudo on SO for the PHS http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11432/how-does-one-know-how-many-times-to-downsample-in-harmonic-product-spectrum